# How to get response parameter in HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to pass some data in one application and get the response from that. For that I am using HttpClient and want to use the value of response in my application. It  may be string, int, or boolean

I wrote the following code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
    "http://index.html?email=" + email + 
    "&password=" + password
);

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8")
    );

    String str = bf.readLine();
        

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error is :- " + e);
}
```

This link will return parameter login=true/false. Now how can I get the value of the login parameter using response?

Comment: you means you want to get the value of the response paramete?

Comment: yes but i got it in String i want it in it's original data type

Comment: So parse it and cast it..

Comment: how i can not get proper way to do this if you know please explain me i am beginner in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All attributes stored in the request are strings. You will have to manually cast it to whatever type they are.

For example you are trying to get a boolean attribute from the request. You will have to do this:

```
String attr = request.getAttribute("nameOfAttribute");
Boolean bool = Boolean.getBoolean(attr);
```

Comment: You say response, yet you demonstrate request.

Comment: Yeah. sorry. Edited it.